# nr. bound variables, missmatch number tokens

Tags: php, variables, pdo, token

Hi I have been scanning the answers on this subject but they seem to be individual at most, so here goes. My code is from a free repository and it works when I remove the addition I have maid.

I added "uname" because I wanted the users to be greeted by their name and not their username. It may be stupied but I like it this way. But I am missing something. My code is here:

```
    <?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    // At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
    if(empty($_SESSION['username'])) 
    { 
        // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
        // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the edit form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the account updating code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
        } 

        // If the user is changing their E-Mail address, we need to make sure that 
        // the new value does not conflict with a value that is already in the system. 
        // If the user is not changing their E-Mail address this check is not needed. 
        if($_POST['email'] != $_SESSION['username']['email']) 
        { 
            // Define our SQL query 
            $query = " 
                SELECT 
                    *
                FROM admin_users 
                WHERE 
                    email = :email
            "; 

            // Define our query parameter values 
            $query_params = array(
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':uname' => $_POST['uname']
            ); 

            try 
            { 
                // Execute the query 
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex) 
            { 
                // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
                // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
                die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
            } 

            // Retrieve results (if any) 
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            if($row) 
            { 
                die("This E-Mail address is already in use"); 
            } 
        } 

        // If the user entered a new password, we need to hash it and generate a fresh salt 
        // for good measure. 
        if(!empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
            $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // If the user did not enter a new password we will not update their old one. 
            $password = null; 
            $salt = null; 
        } 

        // Initial query parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':uname' => $_POST['uname'],
            ':user_id' => $_SESSION['username']['id'],
        ); 

        // If the user is changing their password, then we need parameter values 
        // for the new password hash and salt too. 
        if($password !== null) 
        { 
            $query_params[':password'] = $password; 
            $query_params[':salt'] = $salt; 
        } 

        // Note how this is only first half of the necessary update query.  We will dynamically 
        // construct the rest of it depending on whether or not the user is changing 
        // their password. 
        $query = "
            UPDATE admin_users 
            SET 
                uname = :uname
                email = :email
                username = :username
        "; 

        // If the user is changing their password, then we extend the SQL query 
        // to include the password and salt columns and parameter tokens too. 
        if($password !== null) 
        { 
            $query .= " 
                , password = :password 
                , salt = :salt 
            "; 
        } 

        // Finally we finish the update query by specifying that we only wish 
        // to update the one record with for the current user. 
        $query .= " 
            WHERE 
                id = :user_id 
        "; 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // Now that the user's E-Mail address has changed, the data stored in the $_SESSION 
        // array is stale; we need to update it so that it is accurate. 
        $_SESSION['username']['email'] = $_POST['email']; 

        // This redirects the user back to the members-only page after they register 
        header("Location: private.php"); 

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        die("Redirecting to private.php"); 
    } 

?> 
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>

<div id="header_wrapper">
<h1>Edit Account</h1> 
<form action="edit_account.php" method="post"> 
    Username:<br /> 
    <b><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Navn:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']['uname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Brugernavn:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    E-Mail Address:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br /> 
    <i>(leave blank if you do not want to change your password)</i> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Update Account" /> 
</form>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

The error

> Error: "Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Comment: Error: "Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: oh, thanks, it only on localhost not on the net. But point taken @RiggsFolly